# Объединение нескольких send'ов в один recv

Tags: c++, winapi, сокет, visual-c++, winsock

Может ли случиться так, что все данные, посланные несколькими операциями `send()`, на хосте назначения будут считаны всего одним вызовом `recv()`?

Comment: Да. Может случиться и такое.

Answer (score 3):

Да, но в общем то какая разница. Главное, чтобы данные были полностью приняты, а уж сколько там было отправок не важно.